# Attempting to pass string to std::ifstream as argument

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to use a string retrieved from a vector to pass a filename to ifstream for opening.

```
vector<string> files;

//Populate vector

std::ifstream ifile(files[0] ,std::ios::binary);
```

When compiled This returns:

error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream >::basic_ifstream(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&, const std::_Ios_Openmode&)*

If I attempt to convert files[0] to const char * first

```
vector<string> files;

std::string l = files[0];
const char *p;
p = l.c_str();
std::ifstream ifile(p ,std::ios::binary);
```

The compiler returns:

error: 'l' was not declared in this scope

What am I doing wrong here? It's something basic and glaring i'm sure.

Comment: I don't reproduce your second problem (cutting and pasting your code and adding what is obviously missing).  BTW, you could also use `file[0].c_str()` instead of p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::ifstream ifile(files[0].c_str(), std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: That works, however the code following it now complains that ifile is not declared in this scope.

if (!ifile.good())
        {
            return 1;
        }

Comment: Just a note that you should probably also be checking that the vector is not empty, otherwise `files[0]` will probably give a runtime error or exception.

Comment: I was being a complete idiot and hadn't finished writing an if statement, it all works now, thanks!

Comment: Your original code should magically start working when you upgrade to a C++0x environment.

Comment: Not to hijack this comment thread, but I noticed that passing a string to ifstream worked in gcc 4.4, but wouldn't compile in 4.3.  So is that a c++0x feature added in gcc 4.4+?

Comment: @Matt: I'm not sure, but not being able to pass a string is obviously a mistake.