# C++ how do i use a variable for ifstream

Tags: c++

```
void searchString(const string selection,const string filename)
{
    ifstream myfile;
    string sline;
    string sdata;
    myfile.open(filename);
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        getline(myfile,sline);
        sdata = sdata + sline;
    }
```

How do i use string filename as myfile.open(filename)

Initially i was using file.txt instead, but if i use a variable that pass in by the function, like string filename, it give me an error

```
myfile.open("file.txt");
```

Error message is as followed:

```
main.cpp:203:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(const string&)’
main.cpp:203:25: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:531:7: note: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:531:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Your code should work in C++11. However, it's still worth pointing out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105476/attempting-to-pass-string-to-stdifstream-as-argument?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor for `std::ifstream::open` (for the particular standard of C++ that you're using) doesn't allow a `std::string` argument, so you have to use:

```
 myfile.open(filename.c_str());
```

The constructor expects type `const char *` which you can obtain from a `std::string` object using its `c_str()` member function.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like if they pass `-std=c++11` the code would compile.

Comment: main.cpp:203:26: error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘cstr’

Comment: @user1548465: It's `c_str()`not `cstr()`. The underscore makes a world of difference :)